# How can I make a PasteSpecial table from Excel using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am attempting to copy a range of cells (excel) and PasteSpecial (as an image) into the mail's body using **Outlook vba**, i searched a lot for the solution but i always find how to do that using excel vba.
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

**code Outlook vba**

```
Sub projet()

Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Dim olMailItem1 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xExcelFile As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet



    ' path of the excel file
    xExcelFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Maquette.xlsx"

    ' check if the excel file is open or not
       If IsWorkBookOpen(xExcelFile) = True Then
            Set xExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
            Set xlWB = GetObject(xExcelFile)
            If Not xlWB Is Nothing Then xlWB.Close True
        Else
            Set xExcelApp = New Excel.Application
        End If
         Set xlWB = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
        Set xWs = xlWB.Sheets(1)


    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem3)

    With xlWB.Worksheets(4).Range("A1:C6").Copy
        OutlookMail.Display
        OutlookMail.To = "xxx"
        OutlookMail.CC = "xxx"
        OutlookMail.Subject = "Rapport de supervision : nuit du " & 
        Format(Date- 1, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " au " & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        OutlookMail.Body = xlWB.Worksheets(4).Range("A1:C6").Paste
    End With

    xlWB.Save
    xlWB.Close

    End Sub

    Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
        Dim xFreeFile As Long, xErrNo As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        xFreeFile = FreeFile()
        Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #xFreeFile
        Close xFreeFile
        xErrNo = Err
        On Error GoTo 0
        Select Case xErrNo
            Case 0: IsWorkBookOpen = False
            Case 70: IsWorkBookOpen = True
            Case Else: Error xErrNo
        End Select
    End Function
```

Comment: If you have the excel code then you are on the right track. May I suggest you share that code and show where you get your error.

Comment: @darbid thank you for helping,im gonna share it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Word object model to customize the message body. The [PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pastespecial) method of the `Selection` class inserts the contents of the Clipboard. Here is what MSDN states for the method:

> Unlike with the Paste method, with PasteSpecial you can control the format of the pasted information and (optionally) establish a link to the source file (for example, a Microsoft Excel worksheet). If you do not want to replace the contents of the specified selection, use the Collapse method before you use this method. When you use this method, the selection does not expand to include the contents of the Clipboard.

The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document class:

```
Outlook.Inspector = mail.GetIspector();
Word.Document we = inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
we.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial();
```

Comment: im still new in vba code , so i tried before selection method but i found many errors,i 
 shared my code, so you can explain me more and thank you for your time